# Joomla 2.5 Content Plugin Custom Form not shown

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I'm writing a content plugin for joomla 2.5.

I try to add a custom field for the article. I'm following this guideline http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component, but no chance to get it working.

this part of the code:

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data) {
    if (!($form instanceof JForm))
    {
        $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
        return false;
    }

    // Add the extra fields to the form.
    JForm::addFormPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/oratio');
    $form->loadFile('oratio', false);
    return true;
}
```

does not load the form in the backend article section, but all files exist. Any help please?

EDIT:
this is my form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
  <fields name="oratio">
     <fieldset name="oratio" label="orat.io Comments">
        <field
           name="oratio_enable"
           type="list"
           id="enable"
           description="Enable orat.io Comments"
           label="Enable orat.io Comments"
           default="0"
        >
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
              <option value="0">No</option>
        </field>
        <field
           name="cta_enable"
           type="list"
           id="cta_enable"
           description="Show Call-To-Action"
           label="Show Call-To-Action"
           default="1"
        >
              <option value="1">Yes</option>
              <option value="0">No</option>
        </field>
        <field
           name="cta"
           type="text"
           id="cta"
           description="Call-To-Action"
           label="Call-To-Action"
           default="What's your opinion?"
        >
        </field>
     </fieldset>
  </fields>
</form>
```

Comment: Is the event being triggered at all? Have you tried adding a die to this function to see if the event is triggered?

Comment: yes, event is trigger and i added a die function. I already found the mistake, why it wasn't shown. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could figure it out. The mistake was the name attribute of the `<fields>` tag. It has to be `attribs`. Now it shows up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fields name="attribs">
    ...
```